# Traffic decoration with user-agent header in sharepoint online

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, onedrive

What should be the value of User-Agent header in the http request to microsoft graph api? Based on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#how-to-decorate-your-http-traffic-to-avoid-throttling), the decoration string format for Enterprise Application is like:
`User-Agent = NONISV|CompanyName|AppName/Version`
However when we register an app, we have `AppId` and `App title(or display name)` which is not consistent with what the decoration string is expecting?
Some other blogs mentioned that just the presence of the `user-agent` header string is important and not the value?

Answer (score -1):

The `User-Agent` doesn't really factor into anything when it comes to the Microsoft Graph API - just make it something that identifies your application.

Comment: Thanks @Brad. In order to uniquely identify our application, isn't `App Id` is best to use instead of `App name` (not sure why documentation is referring to App name). As per this link: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app` the same app name can be shared across multiple apps.

Comment: Apparently the user agent *is* considered when it comes to SharePoint throttling considerations, as per documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#how-to-decorate-your-http-traffic

Comment: When you call via Microsoft Graph you're using a token with an app identity (i.e. your call will have an AppID/AppTitle). That is sufficient for the throttling system to appropriately detect your appliaction, so no you don't need to provide a user-agent.